# Best way to measure (and control) the refresh time of some itens of the user interface

Tags: c#, user-interface, begininvoke

My app needs to display the process time of some operations. One of the process times is the time spent to refresh the proces times at the UI ( got it? :D ).

The frequency of the operations can vary from 0 to about 100 Hz (10 ms).

The process times are display in some labels. To set it values I use this static method:

```
public Class UserInteface
{
    //Static action to SafeSetControlText
    private static Action<Control, string> actionSetControlText = delegate(Control c, string txt) { c.Text = txt; };

    //Control
    //Set Text
    public static void SafeSetControlText(Control control, string text, bool useInvoke = false)
    {
        //Should I use actionSetControlText or it is ok to create the delegate every time?
        Action<Control, string> action = delegate(Control c, string txt) { c.Text = txt; };
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            if (useInvoke)
                control.Invoke(action, new object[] { control, text });
            else
                control.BeginInvoke(action, new object[] { control, text });
        }
        else
            action(control, text);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. I dont want to freeze all my UI tryng to update the process times, so how should I control when is it ok to refresh? Now Im doing something like: only update if last update time was 100 ms before now.
2. If I use BegingInvoke, is it possible to **overflow** the queues with too much calls?
3. How can I measure the **UI refresh time** using BeginInvoke? The best way is to use Invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pretty acceptable solution, by me, cause if you do not control it, it can result on data    blinking on UI side.
2. No, I don't think you can overflow, especially on  10 ms, speed.
3. If you want to be sure on time measuring (as much as it possible) the solution is definitely is using of `Invokde`. The same ou an use also in production.

But this is something you gonna to measure against your specific application requirements.

Comment: Humm thanks, and what do you think about the delegate, is it ok to create a new delegate every time or it is better to use a static one?

Comment: @Pedro77: no absolutely not, sorry, I missed this one. Do not create a delegate every time, just create it once in any initialization method.

Comment: Since the methos is static, I think Ill use one static delegate, just like he one on the code above. Is it "bad code"?

Comment: It's clear, it's simple, it doesn't harm a performamce and it works. It's not a bad code.